# Node.js function parameter inject into function

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters

I'm tring to create new function like below

```
function NVConvertToFV (array, func) {
    var funcA = [];
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        var valueF = function (callback) {
            func(array[i], callback);
        }
        funcA[i] = valueF;
    }
    return funcA;
}
```

But, 'func(array[i], callback);' recognized as just a string.

ex.

```
var funcA = [];
var msg = ['hello ', 'it ', 'is ', 'impossible!'];
function alert (para, callback) {
    console.log(para);
    callback(null);
}
funcA = NVConvertToFV(msg, alert);
console.log(String(funcA));
```

results:

```
function (callback) {func(array[i], callback);},
function (callback) {func(array[i], callback);},
function (callback) {func(array[i], callback);},
function (callback) {func(array[i], callback);},
```

Is there any possible way 'func' and 'array[i]' recognized as function and array? like,

```
function (callback) {alert('hello', callback);},
function (callback) {alert('it', callback);},
function (callback) {alert('is', callback);},
function (callback) {alert('impossible', callback);},
```

if someone help me that would be really gladful.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: Are you just asking for the toString to be modified?

Comment: @mscdex use 'async' module to handle multiple task as parallel. And tring to code Object-Oriented Programming. So, I want to make external function to create functions. final goal is like this.   async.parallel(funcA, function(err,results){});

Comment: @ShaBANG no, I use String function to show the results of my NVConvertToFV function. I want to create seperate function which has own variable to use async.parallel() function

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now, other than you'd need to use `array.forEach()` instead of a plain for-loop to be able to create a proper closure around the elements in the array?

Comment: @mscdex Yes! You are Right!!! Thank you! I think my basic of javascript is really poor I should study hard....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `NVConvertToFV()` use `array.forEach()` instead of a normal for-loop in order to correctly capture the current value in the array so that the inner inline callback holds the correct reference. For example:

```
function NVConvertToFV(array, func) {
  var funcA = new Array(array.length);
  array.forEach(function(val, i) {
    funcA[i] = function(callback) {
      func(val, callback);
    };
  });
  return funcA;
}
```